# Bundle asp net images (in vendor) 404

Tags: asp.net, bundle, publish

I need to publish my web application on Azure. On debug in local it's working but when I publish, some images are not loaded. So I published in local and it's the same thing.

[image]

So for me, the problem is :

In debug, images are loaded successfully from **lib/[lib_name]/images/[image_name.png]**

[image]

On the non-bundled version, the css is doing a **../images/[image_to_find.png]**, but on the published version, I got the **Bundles/vendor/css**, but no images. So he is searching for the **Bundles/images/[image_to_find.png]** and return me a *404* in the console.

[image]

This is the part of my BundleConfig.cs

```
    bundles.Add(
        new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/vendor/css")
        .Include("~/fonts/roboto/roboto.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/fonts/material-icons/materialicons.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/toastr/toastr.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/Waves/dist/waves.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/animate.css/animate.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/css/materialize.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/lib/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/css/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/css/themes/all-themes.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
        .Include("~/Views/Shared/_Layout.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())
    );
```

I'm not used to use Bundle, so if you can help me to find what is wrong and how to use images from my libs.

Thanks !